# UrlReferrer - need to find out where it's coming from

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to find out from which page the request is coming from. For instance I have a button in page A and when clicked it redirects as follows

```
http://...../ClientName/names.aspx?nameId=4,
```

Page A's

```
URL = "http://...../Maintenance/names.aspx?nameId=4"
```

In page B, I want to be able to determine if it's coming from Page A. Notice that Page A and Page B have the same ending but in different folders... How can I know in page B if it's coming from the names.aspx in folder Maintenance?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One hint: The URL Referrer is sent by the Browser (Request header). But this is not reliable, since (for instance) security tools might remove it from the request, as do some Proxies. I have used the same concept years back, but later failed because of this reason.

Example: http://darklaunch.com/2011/05/07/chrome-disable-referer-headers

On the other hand, if you can rely on the referrer - e.g. because you are in an Intranet, go ahead - as FT / Kuru said use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer`. Very easy to use.

We have later solved this on application level:

1. Give different HTML forms different logical names
2. You can use hidden form fields to have extra information in the form

Answer (score 1):

```
string myFileName = string.Empty;
System.IO.FileInfo PageFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(Request.UrlReferrer);
myFileName = PageFileInfo.Name;
return myFileName;
```

BTW -- this might not be the best method for security, etc., as UrlReferrers can be spoofed pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer` to determine the referrer. Then you'll have to use RegEx to determine if it is the page you want (depending on how your app works) or String.SubString() to determine it.